# Eror: {"message":"sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: unrecognized token: \"876EL003\"","code":5}

Tags: typescript, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have filter the SQLite data with two conditions. But, I got  unrecognized token error. 
I am not sure if my query statement is wrong on script. Could you please help to check it? Thank you so much. 
I have tried two ways as below:

```
 getEquipmentByTagCode(equipTag,projCode){
    console.log("Equipment Param"+equipTag+projCode);
    return this.database.executeSql('SELECT * FROM equipmentInstall WHERE equipTag=('+equipTag+') AND projCode=('+projCode+') ', []);
  }

getEquipmentByTagCode(equipTag,projCode){
    console.log("Equipment Param"+equipTag+projCode);
    return this.database.executeSql('SELECT * FROM equipmentInstall WHERE equipTag IN ('+equipTag+') AND projCode IN ('+projCode+') ', []);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for error. I missed the double quotes.

```
getEquipmentByTagCode(equipTag,projCode){
    console.log("Equipment Param"+equipTag+projCode);
    return this.database.executeSql('SELECT * FROM equipmentInstall WHERE equipTag="'+equipTag+'" AND projCode="'+projCode+'" ', []); 
  }
```